# How to plot Loss Landscape with more than 2 weights in the network

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, plotting, loss, weights

For a single neuron with **2 weights**, I can plot the loss landscape and it looks like this (OR data, sigmoid activation, MAE loss):

[image]

But, when the neuron accepts more inputs, which means more than 2 weights required, or when there are more neurons, more layers in the network; how should the 3D loss landscape be plotted?

Comment: I don't think you can, as the weights increase so does the number of dimensions. You could perhaps plot 3 weights using color in the graph as the 4th dimension, but I don't think you really could for more

Comment: @Recessive oh, but i can see some very complex loss landscape this way: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/train_val_loss_landscape.png

Comment: the image in the comment right above is from this article: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/14/why-is-my-validation-loss-lower-than-my-training-loss/

Comment: Nope, that's actually just a mislabelled graph by medium. The original is about halfway down this page: http://firsttimeprogrammer.blogspot.com/search/label/Machine%20Learning. You'll see this is a graph for `f(x,y) = x**2 + y**2 –2*x*y`. You can see the (falsely) modified image halfway down this page: https://medium.com/@RosieCampbell/demystifying-deep-neural-nets-efb726eae941. EDIT: The medium post actually specifies this graph is for only 2 weights. It's just the pyimagesearch that loses this in translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not possible to plot loss values (z) against all combinations of weights in all layers, especially when the network is big with thousands or millions of params; in that case, the number of points to plot is too too big.

And also, the 3D space can't be used to plot more than 3 dimensions.

However, with a deep network with lots of weights, these can be plotted:

- Loss value against any pair of 2 weights
- Turn the layer right before output layer (single neuron) into a layer of 2 neurons, and loss can be plotted against these 2 weights (but doesn't make much sense as the meaning of loss value depends on all other weights also)

Example plot when there are 2 neurons in the layer right before output layer (of 1 neuron):

[image]